# How can I set 3d sound to my game in unity5?

Tags: c#, javascript, unity

I have been working on a racing game in unity5. Now I want to set 3d sound so that if the game objects are far away from and coming towards the camera then it sounds like began to attenuate and then louder when closer to the game camera.

But I don't know how to do that.......if anyone knows then please help me out.
Thanks...!

Answer (score 2):

Usualy you have an [audio listener](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-AudioListener.html) atached to your main camera. And an [audio source](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-AudioSource.html) attached to every of your noisy objects. The 3d sound effect is managed by unity. You can "play" with some audio parameters as shown in picture (like doppler level). Enjoy

[image]

Comment: Hmm I have already did it that u given to me....but its not that perfect which I wanted...it seams lack of knowledge...so how can I use it and set good 3d sound? Btw thanks a lot for a quick reply ;)

Comment: @ShraddhaPatel When you want people to help you, you need to describe your setup and your problem more accurately.

Comment: As I described my question above that how can I set 3d sound in racing game? If the game objects are far from the camera then it should sound like real world as low volume and high volume when they come come close towards the camera.

Comment: @ShraddhaPatel how far is "far"? You should be able to control distance volume by setting a reasonable max distance and volume rolloff function.

Comment: Exactly...! I don't know about these parameters actually that is why I am not getting that how to do that...Thanks

Comment: @ShraddhaPatel did you find an answer? I have same problem. If you did could you please share what you have done :D

Comment: No I haven't done that...Actually I don't understand the parameters and settings that is why I asked.